# ImageMagick convert is not adjusting MP4 framerate as expected

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to change the frame rate of a video using ImageMagick’s `convert` tool. This is the command I am using:

```
convert -delay 1 video1.mp4 video2.mp4
```

However, no matter what number I put for the delay, the frame rate does not change (it is stuck at 25FPS). I want it to be 100FPS. I am using the latest ImageMagick version for Windows: ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16.

Why is the delay not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You are using the wrong tool.

### [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org) is for bitmapped image files; not video files.

If you are attempting to change the FPS—or manipulate an MP4 video—then `convert` and the [`-delay`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#delay) option is not going to work. ImageMagick is for bitmapped image files of various kinds. That `-delay` would work for an animated GIF, but not an MP4 file.

What you really need to use is [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org).